# Refactor "using" directives over an entire codebase?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, refactoring, using-directives

One of the things I love about Visual Studio 2008 is the ability to refactor and reorganize the "using" directives in source code files (this may have been in 2005 as well, I don't remember).

Specifically, I'm talking about how you can have it both reorganize the directives to be alphabetical (though with the core FCL libraries floating to the top) and removing any directives which don't need to be there (either never used or no longer used).

Is there any way to automate this refactoring (the sorting and trimming) across an entire old codebase? Either through all of the files in a solution or across multiple solution files.

Comment: You are referring to the [Using Directive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf0df423.aspx), not the [Using Statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx).  No matter how many tools documentation pages misuse the terminology, a using directive is not a statement.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe you can do it solution wide using [Power Commands](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/PowerCommands)

From PowerCommands Documentation:

> Remove and Sort Usings
>   This command removes and sort using statements for all classes given a project. It is useful, for example, in removing or organizing the using statements generated by a wizard. This command can be executed from a solution node or a single project node.

Comment: Couldn't have answered it better myself.

Comment: Oh wow I just showed this around the office and now I'm like the hero of the day. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

[ReSharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper) is a (commercial) Visual Studio plugin that has a "Code Cleanup" utility than can be run at a solution-wide level.  The utility detects and removes unreferenced using statements, and performs other useful maintenance.  I am unsure if it provides functionality to sort them, however.

Comment: I'm not sure if it does by default, but if it doesn't the StyleCop plugin for it definitely does.

Answer (score 1):

Use PowerCommands addon for Visual Studio '08. You can right click the solution in the Solution Explorer and choose "Remove And Sort" usings.  Also, there are options in the Tools-->Options dialog box (scroll down to the Power Commands item) for removing on save and reformatting your code ( using vs settings ) on save.